# What year Camaro is this?

Tags: chevrolet, camaro, vehicle-identification

Hope this isn't a poor question for the site but I came across this camaro online but don't know much about it.

[image]

I suppose a plus would be that when other's do a search for this picture mechanics.SE will pop up with specs!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a 1967 Camaro which Chip Foose rebuilt on an episode of [Overhaulin'](http://www.velocity.com/tv-shows/overhaulin/videos/1967-camaro.htm). The sign in the background is the clue.

**EDIT:** I guess I could tell you ***how*** to tell this is a '67 with or without knowing Chip Foose did this build :-) If you know anything about Camaros, you can tell this is a 1st gen by its angular cuts. The 2nd gens are not angular and are a lot longer looking. So since you know it's a 1st gen, you should know the 1st gen covers the years of 67-69. To figure out which year specifically it is, the first thing to look at are the wheel wells. The 69 has squarish wells, while the 67-68 have round wells which follows the tires quite well. Looking at this one, you can see they are very much round. To tell the difference between the 67-68, look to see if it has a wing window on the door (just behind and inline with the A-pillar). The 67 has one while the 68 does not. There really isn't too much of a difference between them otherwise.

Comment: Awesome breakdown of how to tell it's a '67! Let me guess...you like cars??

Comment: @RSW ... Well, yes ... yes I do :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a 1967 model as my grand father had the same model that I had seen in the photo album of our family members.